# Jumping to brackets from foreach/if declaration after postfix autocompletion

Tags: php, phpstorm

So a situation:

I type out this expresion $items.fe, autocomplete it with TAB. and i end up like this:

```
foreach ($items as $item/*CARET HERE*/)
{

}
```

Anyway to jump from current caret location, to within the braces?

As well it is requirement at my work to not have any brackets if only one statement in the if/foreach/while etc.. Any quick way to remove them, if I only have one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyway to jump from current caret location, to within the braces?

There is no Eclipse-style of escaping from current bracket/quote/etc: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6984

But, since postfix completions utilize [Live Templates](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm) mechanics, you can just press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>one more time to move to next edit/entry point, which, in your case, will be inside braces.

> As well it is requirement at my work to not have any brackets if only one statement in the if/foreach/while etc.. Any quick way to remove them, if I only have one statement?

I may only suggest to use `Edit | Extend Selection` -- inside empty brackets it will select everything between `{` and `}` (including actual brackets).

Comment: If I press tab, it auto completes my variable name. So I need to press ESC in order to avoid that. So I mapped my CAPS LOCK (who uses it anyway). To act as ESC, so now it is quite painless. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I wrote it after testing it myself (although with one difference: I do not have code completion poping up automatically -- I prefer calling it only when needed manually). Based on your description you have completed your `$item` variable name with `TAB` already (which means -- no code completion pop up is visible) .. so pressing `Tab` should not interfere here (although yes -- `Enter` is safer). Possibly my setup still differs from yours that it is necessary to use `Esc`...